# Entity Framework - Removing virtual keyword from navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I am using entity framework with database first approach, along with EF 4.x DBContext Generator. All my entity classes have navigation properties which are marked as "virtual". I want to remove virtual keyword from all my entity classes. There are around 350 entity classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must modify T4 template (.tt) file to remove virtual keyword.

Comment: Which (.tt) file to be modified to achieve the same

Comment: Model1.tt file must be modified to achieve the same. Remove virtual from line number 255

Comment: I am using VS2015, where can I find this file Model1.tt or T4 template your talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Removing virtual will mean that you are unable to use lazy loading for entity framework. In my opinion lazy loading has a very limited scope and is mostly misused (which often causes performance issues). However do note that when you turn it off you may need to adjust your code to manually load additional navigation properties when you retrieve data. You can do this by using .`Include` in your EF query

To remove the virtual flag you probably need to disable lazy loading in your EF generator.

Comment: Disabling lazy loading doesn't remove "virtual" keyword from navigation properties. As far as I know "virtual" is also responsible for efficient change tracking

Comment: @user1373280 virtual is also used for Proxy Entities, however this needs to decorate *all* properties on an entity not just navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this VS extension, It adds (among other things) fine control over the virtual modifier:
[EF Designer Extender](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/aec90b18-916f-4316-a9c2-ba3d61ab9ae5)